# UnitTest the team foundation client api for workitems using moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tfs, moq, tfs-workitem

How can i test the team foundation client API using MOQ Framework.

I have an interface created in my project to get the WorkItemCollection by querying using WIQL.

```
public TFS.WorkItemCollection GetWorkItemCollection(string query)
{
    TFS.Project project = this.TfsWorkItemStore.Projects[this.TeamProjectName];
    return project.Store.Query(query);
}
```

Since the return type is WorkItemCollection which is a sealed class i cannot Moq it.

WorkITemCollection constructor cannot have null values else it throws exception so i have to actually create a valid object for purpose of unit testing.

```
WorkItemCollection workItemCollection = WorkItemProject.GetWorkItemCollection(taskQuery);

foreach (TFS.WorkItem tfsWorkItem in workItemCollection)
{
   ////WorkItem to Model conversion
}
```

Any advice on how to use Moq to test it

Comment: Not clear what you're trying to test.  Can you describe the test you'd like to write? Then we can see if you could use Moq to write it.

Comment: MockWorkItemTeamProjectCollection.Setup(x => x.GetWorkItemCollection(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(It.IsAny<WorkItemCollection>()); which obviously makes returned workitemcollection as null. When i try to create a Mock object of WorkItemCollection it fails since its a sealed class. I have put in actual Query and WorkItemStore object

Comment: You are testing some class that calls GetWorkItemCollection?  Then you should return a real WorkItemCollection from the call.

Comment: GetWorkItemCollection is my own method which calls teamfoundation api to get the workitemcollection from TFS. If i get real data then i am actually making a call to TFS server which i shouldn't be doing in unit test

Comment: Yes, you don't want to call the TFS server in your unit test.  Can you create a WorkItemCollection using its constructor in your unit test without accessing the TFS server?  If so, then use that in the Returns of your Moq Setuo.  If not, then you need your own class MyWorkItemCollection (with a better name!) that contains the data you're interested in from WorkItemCollection, so you can use that in your Returns

Comment: Thanks. Let me try that